# How can I remove "Loading..." label from MPMoviePlayerViewController?

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6

I have a MPMoviePlayerViewController, I don't want to initialize it with a content url, I just want to have a empty movie player GUI out there. Whenever I want it to load a movie, it then starts loading. But I can't

```
self.playerViewController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] init];

MPMoviePlayerController *player = [self.playerViewController moviePlayer];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlayerPlaybackStateChanged:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification object:nil];

player.shouldAutoplay = FALSE;
player.initialPlaybackTime = 0;
[player setFullscreen:FALSE];


[player.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, -20, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height/2)];
[self.view addSubview:player.view];
```

As you see, I init the MPMoviePlayerViewController with no content url, and I set the autoplay to false, but when I run the application. Even though there is no video url given, I can still see a label "Loading ..." near the "Done" button, why???? How can I remove the loading label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use MPMoviePlayerController instead of MPMoviePlayerViewController. You'll need to build a view controller around it if you want to display it modally.

You could also maybe iterate through `[MPMoviePlayerViewController view].subviews` until you find the UILabel, but that approach might break in future versions of iOS.